# How to make a edit announce command in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots, discord.js

I am having an announce command, that command help users on Discord to send custom embeds, but I want to make an edit announce command that will help users to edit the embed sent by them with the help of that message ID. My announce code is attached below, please guide me on how to make an edit announce command.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');



module.exports = {
    name: "announce",
    category: "Moderation",
    aliases: ["announcement", "broadcast"],
    description: "Announce a embedded message",
    async run(client, message, args) {

        if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.channel.send('You can\'t use that!')
        if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.channel.send('I don\'t have the right permissions.')

        message.delete();
        let split = '|';

        if(!args[0]) {

            const invalid = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setAuthor("Announce", client.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: "png", dynamic: true, size: 2048 }))
            .setColor("#eb0936")
            .setTitle("Invalid Argument")
            .setDescription("**USAGE**\n`announce <embedTitle>|<embedMessage>|<embedColor>|<embedThubmnail>|<embedImage>`\n\n**FOR MORE HELP**\n`helpannounce`")
            
            return message.channel.send({embed: invalid})
        }

        args = args.join(' ').split(split)

        for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) args[i].trim();

        if (args[5]) args[5] = parseInt(`0x${args[5]}`);    

        let options = {
            title: args[0] ,
            message: args[1] || 'Undefined',
            embedColor: args[2] || 0xffffff,
            thumbnail: args[3],
            image: args[4]
            
          


        }

        const embed =  new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(options.embedColor)
            .setTitle(options.title)
            .setThumbnail(options.thumbnail)
            .setImage(options.image)
            
            
            
            if (options.message) embed.setDescription(options.message);
            

           message.channel.send(embed)



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an `editAnnounce` command:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  name: 'editAnnounce',
  category: 'Moderation',
  aliases: ['editAnnouncement', 'editBroadcast'],
  description: 'Edit an announcement',
  async run(client, message, args) {
    if (!args[0] || !(args[1] || args[2] || args[3] || args[4] || args[5])) {
      const invalid = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor('Announce', client.user.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'png', dynamic: true, size: 2048 }))
        .setColor('#eb0936')
        .setTitle('Invalid Arguments')
        .setDescription('**USAGE**\n`announce <messageID> [embedTitle]|[embedMessage]|[embedColor]|[embedThumbnail]|[embedImage]`\n*leaving a field blank will result in that field remaining unmodified.*');

      return message.reply(invalid);
    }

    message.delete();

    const msg = await message.channel.messages.fetch(args[0]);
    if (!msg) return message.reply('the specified message could not be found.');
    if (!msg.embeds[0]) return message.reply('the specified message does not contain an embed.');

    const oldFields = msg.embeds[0];
    const fields = args.slice(1).join(' ').split('|').map(arg => arg.trim());

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();

    if (fields[0] || oldFields.title) embed.setTitle(fields[0] || oldFields.title);
    if (fields[1] || oldFields.description) embed.setDescription(fields[1] || oldFields.description);
    if (fields[2] || oldFields.color) embed.setColor(fields[2] || oldFields.color);
    if (fields[3] || oldFields.thumbnail && oldFields.thumbnail.url) embed.setThumbnail(fields[3] || oldFields.thumbnail.url);
    if (fields[4] || oldFields.image && oldFields.image.url) embed.setImage(fields[4] || oldFields.image.url);

    msg.edit(embed);
  }
};
```

Comment: Its giving an error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Object.run (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\rilpbot-master\commands\moderation\editannounce.js:21:20)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

Comment: @Ritam110204 Try it now.

Comment: Its running well but some problems are coming like when I am editing an embed thats having title, descriptio, color, thumbnail, image and I want to edit the color of the embed its giving an error. You can come in my TRIAL server and test there LINK :https://discord.gg/QChS8bn